# Can able to Send SMS using twilio API in java

Tags: java, twilio

From Jave Code using "sms.getStatus()" method I am getting SMS Sent Status as "queued" and in Twilio wep page under Log section it is showing as "Sent",But I didnt get any SMS.can i get help for resolving this problem?

**Details :-**

FromNumber :- which i got while doing registration

ToNumber :- indian number

Comment: If the Twilio website itself is showing the status as sent, there is nothing related to this website. You should probably go ask Twilio, or your carrier or both.

Comment: okay,thank you..only thing i want to verify..actually from number is us number and to is india number,Will this cause any problem?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

Sending SMS messages to India has a number of limitations.  Check out the following FAQ for more info:

https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/are-there-limitations-on-sending-sms-messages-to-indian-mobile-devices

Hope that helps.